# CSS framework for documentation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, documentation

I am writing a document for a Rails application that I wrote. 
Apart from a word document, I need it to be a web document as well. And since I do not have a lot of time, I was wondering if there is a CSS framework that will help me facilitating the process.

So is there a CSS framework that is specifically designed for documentation with Ruby syntax highlighting?

I am not even sure if syntax highlighting is possible only with CSS. Any recommendation will be appreciated!

Comment: Syntax highlighting with just CSS is impossible. You need elements to hang off (e.g. <code class="ruby function">)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout [SHJS](http://shjs.sourceforge.net/) - SHJS is a JavaScript program which highlights source code passages in HTML documents. Documents using SHJS are highlighted on the client side by the web browser.

It's not a CSS solution, but if I'm understanding what you are trying to accomplish should give you similar results.